# How do I refer to a data_table during an insert trigger function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I am working with Postgresql und try to define a trigger function. Everytime a row is added to a special table, is should gather informations form several tables und add a DS in a different row.

This is what I got by now.

```
CREATE FUNCTION tf_mdo.insert_new_package()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$

insert into v_triple_o_view (offerer_id, location_id) 
            Values (new.id, foreigntables.id where foreigntables.offerer = new.id)
$BODY$ ;

ALTER FUNCTION tf_mdo.insert_new_package()
    OWNER TO myadmin;
```

Now I would like to insert into "location_id" a special "id" from foreigntables. Excatly that one, that has got in offerer the new.id.

What is the correct syntax for doing so?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a select statement for insert.

```
insert into v_triple_o_view (offerer_id, location_id) 
            SELECT new.id, f.id FROM foreigntables f where f.offerer = new.id
```